# automating OSX 10.9.2

Tags: macos

http://youtu.be/xi5UuemkYd0 is a video that kinda shows what I need to do.
I have two things i need. The first is software that can control the mouse on osx 10.9.2. What needs to happen is it needs to go up and click aux 1 and go down and click say ProPresenter. Then it would do the same for aux 2 and 3.

The second thing i need is a way to make sure any key presses do not interact with the ATEM software. I was thinking about some sort of say 10-15 key external keyboard that did not map to normal keys. Not sure though.

A bit more info on what I am doing here. This software controls a video switcher board at our church. Auxes 1,2,3 and 4 are respectively front screen, back screen, choir screens and a screen in front of stage.

At different time during the service I have to switch between sources. At the moment I am rapidly clicking each aux but when you are switching 4 sources at once it gets a hair too slow. So I want to set up a way to hit a single button to do what i need. I am not sure but I figure I could get away with about 5-10 different scenes set up.

The other issue is that the ATEM software also controls the main video switcher as well as the aux screens and I really do not need to hit any keys that make it do anything because we are live on TV at this point and I do not need to be messing up the rest of the team.

Comment: So let  us see your work so far !

Comment: You don't need to control the mouse in this way. There are simpler methods. Basically, you want to command the menus by using AppleScript. Manual mouse control is too problem-prone to script reliably. I'll throw something together and see if it works. I can't test it directly on the app since I don't have it, but presumably you can! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this AppleScript code does what you want. It should click the menu item "ProPresenter" of the menus "Aux1", "Aux2" and "Aux3" as you requested:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell menu bar 1 of application process "ATEM Software Control"
    click menu item "ProPresenter" of menu "Aux1" of menu bar item "Aux1"
    click menu item "ProPresenter" of menu "Aux2" of menu bar item "Aux2"
    click menu item "ProPresenter" of menu "Aux3" of menu bar item "Aux3"
end tell
```

To set this up as a keyboard shortcut, use the following steps:

1. Open Automator
2. Create a new Service
   [image: select service]
3. Add a single Run AppleScript action to your Service with the following code:

   ```
   tell application "System Events" to tell menu bar 1 of application process "ATEM Software Control"
       click menu item "ProPresenter" of menu "Aux1" of menu bar item "Aux1"
   end tell
   ```

   [image: service setup up]
   Make sure it's set to receive "no input" and work in "ATEM Software Control". Click on "any application", then "other", and navigate to the app.
4. Save it with a name of your choosing.
5. Now, go into Keyboard preferences, click on the "Shortcuts" tab, then click on "Services". Your newly created service should be at the bottom. Click on it, and click on "add shortcut" and specify a shortcut to your liking.

[image: add shortcut]

6. Lastly, go into "Security and Privacy" settings, click on the "Privacy" tab, and then "Accessibility". Make sure you see Automator in the list. If not, click on the lock on the bottom left and enter your password, then click on the "+" and add Automator to the list.

[image]

7. Repeat this with modified AppleScript code for each camera you need to switch between, with a different shortcut for each.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Ill try it tomorrow. I still need to figure out how to tie 5-10 of these to single buttons I can press. I have added a bit more to the main question on what I am trying to do now that I am not posting it on mobile.

Comment: The edit should do what you want now!

Comment: Ok I tried it but I got an error while trying to run it in automator itself. http://imgur.com/bzTYrgI I went ahead and gave it a shortcut because I had read somewhere that the program being controlled had to be in the foreground but it seems to do nothing. Is there anymore info I can give you?

Comment: Run this script for me in Script Editor:`tell application "System Events" to get menu items of menus of menu bar 1 of application process "ATEM Software Control" whose name is "ProPresenter"`

Comment: It gave me the following. "{{}, {}}"

Comment: well that's odd... Try this: `tell application "System Events" to get UI elements of menu bar 1 of application process "ATEM Software Control"

Comment: Ill see if i can stop by the church tomorrow otherwise it may be next Sunday. I just got kicked out cause everyone was going home.